# Having trouble with AsyncTask using a recursive method

Tags: multithreading, android-asynctask

I've been reading about AsyncTasks and Hanlders and Loopers but I still can't figure out where I'm going wrong in my code.  I'm trying to run code that will look over a Tic Tac Toe grid and determine the best move for the computer.  I want this code to run in the background 'cause it can take some time and then I can update the UI level with a textbox that says something like "I'm Thinking".  I've tried this a bunch of different ways, none with success.

```
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {  
    private Board _b;
    private Welcome.Player _opp;
    private int _depth;

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {  
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected void SetVars(Board b, Player p, int depth){
        _b = b;
        _opp = p;
        _depth = depth;
    }

    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Looper.prepare();
        try{
            _bestMove = _b.GetBestMove(_opp,_depth);
        }
        catch(Exception err){
            _bestMove = -1;
        }
       return "All done";
    }  

    @Override 
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {  
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);  
    }  

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       if(_bestMove == -1){
           TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Score);
           tv.setText("Had and error, couldn't make a move."); 
       }
       FollowUpComputerMove(this);
   }
```

The above code will work for exactly 5 moves and then it crashes.  When I watch in the debugger I see new theads being created named Thread<#> AsyncTask #1.  Once I get to five of those AsyncTasks it goes back to try and grab the first AsyncTask and crashes.  When it crashes I'm shown the ThreadPoolExecutor.class file.

I've also read that I shouldn't be using both the AsyncTask and the Looper objects together so I've tried taking the Loooper.prepare() statement out, but then my AsyncTask fails immediately with the error message:

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() - AsyncTask inside a dialog
```

I've read repeatedly that you shouldn't be trying to update the UI from an AsyncTask and that often the above error is because of that, but GetBestMove isn't updating the UI thread.  When I trace through to see where the error comes, it fails when calling a constructor saying it can't find the class.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  My end goal is to use one main thread and only one background thread, and just keep re-using the background thread whenever the computer needs to make a move.  I know that the recursive method GetBestMove works when I run this program in a single-thread manner.  But the screen freezes for too long on some moves as the method is being run.  Thank you so much.

-NifflerX

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering my own question, but the issue I was facing had nothing to do with recursion.  The class I was calling was extending the class Activity, and while trying to call that from an AsyncTask the program was erroring out.  When I removed the extends Activity from the class definition it started working again.  Sorry for the post.

-NifflerX